# "No Endpoints classes detected." when trying to build Google Cloud Endpoints project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm in the process of following the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) for Google Cloud Endpoints in Java using Maven and I can't access my endpoints with the API Explorer.

For the most part I've followed the guide, though I have added a little structure to my project.  My root project package is `com.ryanharter.devinfo` and my endpoints live in a `com.ryanharter.devinfo.spi` package, while my model classes are in `com.ryanharter.devinfo.beans` (This is modeled after the Mobile Backend Starter).

I've written my Endpoints class and annotated it like so:

```
@Api(name = "deviceinfo", 
     version = "v1",
     namespace = @ApiNamespace(
        ownerDomain = "ryanharter.com",
        ownerName = "ryanharter.com", 
        packagePath = "devinfo")
     )
public class DeviceInfoV1 {

    @ApiMethod(name = "list", path = "devices", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public DeviceListDto list(QueryDto query) {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

All of that seems fine and matches other working projects I have, but when I run the dev server I get a blank screen.

I've also noticed that my maven log shows this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ devinfo ---
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /path/to/devinfo/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.7:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) @ devinfo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - get endpoints discovery doc...
[INFO] No Endpoints classes detected.
```

I see that there are "No Endpoints classes detected."  I also notice that `/path/to/devinfo/target/classes` is empty.

Aside from package structure and class content I've followed the guide linked above to the letter, as far as I can tell.

**EDIT:**

In response to Dan, here's the contents of my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app
        version="2.5"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

</web-app>
```

Per the documentation linked above, I haven't touched this.  This is just what the Maven archetype generated.  I have seen reports online of the need to manually map my endpoints in the `web.xml`, but the doc says nothing about this so I assumed a maven goal was going to be taking care of that for me.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your web.xml file?

Comment: Thanks @DanHolevoet, I've edited the question to include the contents of the web.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try running: mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib

Additionally, I do not know if you use the google plugin for eclipse. mine automatically updates the web.xml to contain my controller classes for the endpoints. The endpoints of my project looks a bit like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>package.endpointsController,package.anotherTestcontroller</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Maven will handle the mapping in `web.xml`, sorry about that.

Can you try something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.google.devrel.samples.helloendpoints.Greetings,com.google.devrel.samples.helloendpoints.FooBar</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Use your own classes in place of `com.google.devrel.samples.helloendpoints.Greetings` and `com.google.devrel.samples.helloendpoints.FooBar` in the file.

This will register your API classes with the servlet that handles incoming requests.

Comment: I've tried this but get no change in the maven output, still no client libs.

Comment: I figured this one out.  I've been running `mvn clean appengine:endpoints_generate_client_lib`, but the appengine:endpoints_generate_client_lib target is dependant on compilation, but doesn't say that anywhere.  So when I run `mvn clean package appengine:endpoints_generate_client_lib` things work out just fine (except that it puts the libs in my current directory, not the target dir).